# Show All Product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, disable

I want to show all product if it is enable or disabled doesn't matter.

with this

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
```

I only get enabled product please help me with that to get disabled product also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found two solution on this, please try first one, if it does not work for you, then you can try 2nd one.

You can use disable stock check on your collection by this:

```
$productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
$productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
```

Or else you can use this:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->load();
            // Patch to alter load and get disabled products too
       $collection->clear();
            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('where');
            foreach ($where as $key => $condition)
            {
                if(strpos($condition, 'stock_status_index.stock_status = 1') !== false){
                    $updatedWhere[] = 'AND (stock_status_index.stock_status IN (1,0))';
                } else {
                    $updatedWhere[] = $condition;
                }   
            }
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart('where', $updatedWhere);
            $collection->load();
```

Comment: Actually i have used it in my Block file then return it and use that in phtml file how to do that !@Shoaib

Comment: have you used this model? `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`

Comment: I have solved it with your provided parameter
$productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false); 
Thanks

Comment: Please Look into that question 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316851/magento-2-how-can-i-update-product-price-from-frontend/316855?noredirect=1#comment454436_316855

Comment: Will you tell me how to get only disabled product @Shoaib

Comment: Instead of `AND (stock_status_index.stock_status IN (1,0))` you can use `AND (stock_status_index.stock_status =0)`